# This iMessage application is missing its required iMessage app extension

Tags: ios-app-extension, required

I have already thoroughly reviewed the other answers for this question which has been asked several times. As the others, it works on simulator but not on my iPhone or iPad.

I **have** confirmed that yes (and it was working fine before I upgraded to xcode 8.2.1),

> deployment target is less than your device iOS version. If you are
>   running Xcode Beta with deployment target 10.1, your device must be at
>   least on same beta version. Reduce your deployment target to 10.0
>   otherwise.

I am running 10.1.1 and the deployment target is at 10.0

Any ideas on what else the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

Change the Deoloyment Target for both of your project and StickerPackExtension to 10.0, the problem might be solved.